# Spectrum of the operator $A(f,g)=(g,\Delta f-f)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces, spectral-theory

Let $\Omega$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R^n}$. We consider the product Hilbert space $H=H^1_0(\Omega)\times L^2(\Omega)$ with the norm
$$|(f,g)|^2=\int_\Omega (|\nabla f|^2+|f|^2+|g|^2 ) dx$$ 
We consider the operator $A:D(A)\to H$ defined  by

$$A\begin{pmatrix}
       f  \\
        g  
       \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}
       0 & I \\
        \Delta-I & 0 
       \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
       f  \\
        g  
       \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
       g  \\
        \Delta f-f 
       \end{pmatrix}$$
with domain
$$D(A)=\left\{ \begin{pmatrix}
       f  \\
        g  
       \end{pmatrix}\in H, \ \ \ \Delta f\in L^2(\Omega) \ \ and \ \ \ g\in H^1_0(\Omega) \right\}$$
How can we find the spectrum of this operator in the case $\Omega$ is bounded and in the case $\Omega=\mathbb{R^n}$. If I am not wrong, we can see that $A$ is a skew adjoint operator.

Comment: Are you sure about that domain? Don't you need two weak derivatives for the Laplacian? Are you using $(\cdot,\cdot)$ in different ways?

Comment: @T.A.E. Yes, in the domain $f$ should have two weak derivatives, I see this in a lot of books, they just put $\Delta f \in L^2$ instead of $\Delta f$ exists and belongs to $L^2$.

Comment: Please be specific about the domain for $\Delta$. There are several possibilities. Plus, what does $A(f,g)=(g,\Delta f - f)$ mean? Is the range of $A$ in $L^{2}\times L^{2}$ or is the term on the right an inner-product?

Comment: I consider the product space as a Hilbert space, so $A$ is a matrix operator, I will edit the question to make it clear.

Answer (score 3):

Because nobody is answering, I thought I'd offer a start. Your equation for the resolvent of $A$ is
$$
              (\lambda I -A)\left(\begin{array}{c}f \\ g\end{array}\right)=
              \left(\begin{array}{cc}\lambda & -I \\
                                      I-\Delta & \lambda\end{array}\right)
              \left(\begin{array}{c}f \\ g\end{array}\right)
                            =\left(\begin{array}{c}h \\ k\end{array}\right).
$$
Equivalently,
$$
\begin{align}
   \lambda f - g = h  & \implies g=\lambda f - h\\
   (I-\Delta)f +\lambda g = k & \implies (I-\Delta)f+\lambda^{2}f=k+\lambda h
\end{align}
$$
Given $h$, $k$, this amounts to solving for $f$ such that
$$
            -\Delta f+(1+\lambda^{2})f = k+\lambda h,
$$
and then setting $g=\lambda f-h$. All of this comes down to knowing when
$-1-\lambda^{2}\in\sigma(-\Delta)$. So it seems that
$$
               \sigma(A) = \pm i\sqrt{\sigma(-\Delta)+1}.
$$
I'm being a little sloppy about the details.